# How can I iterate over a recordset within a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, stored-procedures, iteration

I need to iterate over a recordset from a stored procedure and execute another stored procedure using each fields as arguments. I can't complete this iteration in the code. I have found samples on the internets, but they all seem to deal with a counter. I'm not sure if my problem involved a counter. I need the T-SQL equivalent of a **foreach**

Currently, my first stored procedure stores its recordset in a temp table, #mytemp. I assume I will call the secondary stored procedure like this:

```
while (something)
    execute nameofstoredprocedure arg1, arg2, arg3
end
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You need to create a cursor to loop through the record set.

Example Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Customers
(
    CustomerId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1)
    ,FirstName Varchar(50) 
    ,LastName VARCHAR(40)
)

INSERT INTO Customers VALUES('jane', 'doe')
INSERT INTO Customers VALUES('bob', 'smith')
```

Cursor:

```
DECLARE @CustomerId INT, @FirstName VARCHAR(30), @LastName VARCHAR(50)

DECLARE @MessageOutput VARCHAR(100)

DECLARE Customer_Cursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT CustomerId, FirstName, LastName FROM Customers


OPEN Customer_Cursor 

FETCH NEXT FROM Customer_Cursor INTO
    @CustomerId, @FirstName, @LastName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @MessageOutput = @FirstName + ' ' + @LastName



    RAISERROR(@MessageOutput,0,1) WITH NOWAIT

    FETCH NEXT FROM Customer_Cursor INTO
    @CustomerId, @FirstName, @LastName
END
CLOSE Customer_Cursor
DEALLOCATE Customer_Cursor
```

Here is a link to MSDN on how to create them.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx

This is why I used Raise Error instead of PRINT for output.
https://kemiller2002.github.io/2014/11/24/Wait-Wait-Don-t-Tell-Me-On-Second-Thought.html

Comment: I was able to port the eggheadcafe.com link to my code. thanks

Comment: The egghead article did it!

Comment: This answer has been flagged for removal because it is a link-only answer whose link is now broken. Could you please expand the answer to fully address the question without requiring the reader to click through the link?

Comment: You should avoid cursors. There are many cursorless approaches. Even one below.

Comment: I get an error "Syntax error: 'FROM' (from) is not valid input at this position" at `FETCH NEXT FROM Customer_Cursor INTO CustomerId, FirstName, LastName;`. Can you please help me?

Comment: CustomerId etc need to be variables.  Should be @CustomerId and you'll have to declare them beforehand of you didn't.

Comment: @kemiller2002 I then get "Syntax error: unexpected '@CustomerId' (at text suffix)"

Answer (score 16):

It's very easy to loop through the rows in SQL procedure. You just need to use a cursor. Here is an example:

Let us consider a table **Employee** with column **NAME** and **AGE** with 50 records into it and you have to execute a stored procedure say **TESTPROC** which will take name and age parameters of each row.

```
create procedure CursorProc
as
begin
   declare @count bigint;
   declare @age varchar(500)
   declare @name varchar(500)
   select @count = (select count(*) from employee)
   declare FirstCursor cursor for select name, age from employee
   open FirstCursor 
   while @count > 0
      begin
         fetch FirstCursor into @name, @age
         Exec TestProc @name, @age
         set @count = @count - 1
      end
   close FirstCursor 
   deallocate FirstCursor 
end
```

Make sure you deallocate the cursor to avoid errors.

Comment: you saved my day. My first stored procedure ever :)

Answer (score 11):

try this (cursor free looping):

```
CREATE TABLE #Results  (RowID  int identity(1,1), Col1  varchar(5), Col2 int, ... )
DECLARE @Current  int
       ,@End      int
DECLARE @Col1  varchar(5)
       ,@Col2 int
       ,...

--you need to capture the result set from the primary stored procedure
INSERT INTO #Results
    (Col1, COl2,...)
    EXEC nameofstoredprocedure_1 arg1, arg2, arg3
SELECT @End=@@ROWCOUNT,@Current=0

--process each row in the result set
WHILE @Current<@End
BEGIN
    SET @Current=@Current+1

    SELECT
        @Col1=COl1, @Col2=Col2
        FROM #Results
        WHERE RowID=@Current

    --call the secondary procedure for each row
    EXEC nameofstoredprocedure_2  @Col1, @Col2,...

END
```

working example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE nameofstoredprocedure_1
(@arg1 int, @arg2 int, @arg3 int)
AS
SELECT 'AAA',@arg1 UNION SELECT 'BBB',@arg2 UNION SELECT 'CCC',@arg3
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE nameofstoredprocedure_2
(@P1 varchar(5), @P2 int)
AS
PRINT '>>'+ISNULL(@P1,'')+','+ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(10),@P2),'')
GO

CREATE TABLE #Results  (RowID  int identity(1,1), Col1  varchar(5), Col2 int)
DECLARE @Current  int
       ,@End      int
DECLARE @Col1  varchar(5)
       ,@Col2 int


INSERT INTO #Results
    (Col1, COl2)
    EXEC nameofstoredprocedure_1 111, 222, 333
SELECT @End=@@ROWCOUNT,@Current=0

WHILE @Current<@End
BEGIN
    SET @Current=@Current+1

    SELECT
        @Col1=COl1, @Col2=Col2
        FROM #Results
        WHERE RowID=@Current

    EXEC nameofstoredprocedure_2  @Col1, @Col2

END
```

OUTPUT:

```
(3 row(s) affected)
>>AAA,111
>>BBB,222
>>CCC,333
```

Comment: when i tried this with my code, the loop never executed with 21 records in #mytemp

Comment: It works for me.  between the `SELECT @End=@@ROWCOUNT,@Current=0` and `WHILE @Current<@End` add this: `print 'will process '+ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(5),@End),'')+' rows'` and between the `SET @Current=@Current+1` and the `SELECT...` add this: `print '    processing row '+ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(5),@Current),'')`  Also, if you are NOT populating #Results with the insert and running the WHILE at the same time you can add this, before the while: `SELECT @End=COUNT(*) FROM #Results`

Comment: cursors are bad, post your modification of my answer and I'll point out your error. I'd rather poke out my eye before I'd use a cursor.